# C printf() formatting: Float doesn't seem to right justify.

Tags: c, formatting, printf

Something weird is happening when I try to format this output, it seems like the floats aren't right justified?

I want the decimal points to line up... Am I doing something wrong?

```
if (flushParams -> Volume > 0)
{   
    printf("\n      %-23s %7ld %2s  %7ld %3s  %2s %4.1f %1s  %9s %4.1f %2s %9s %4.1f %2s",
           "Intake Flush",
           event_data -> water1.ml, "ml",
           event_data -> water1.secs, "sec",
           "LB", event_data -> water1.bat, "V",
           "Average I", event_data -> water1.average_current, "mA",
           "Highest I", event_data -> water1.highest_current,  "mA");
    Message(event_data -> water1.message);
    printf("\n      %-11s = %02d", "Flush port", event_data -> portwater);
}
printf("\n\n      %-23s %7ld %2s  %7ld %3s  %2s %4.1f %1s  %9s %4.1f %2s %9s %4.1f %2s",
       "Sample",
       event_data -> sample.ml, "ml",
       event_data -> sample.secs, "sec",
       "LB", event_data -> sample.bat, "V",
       "Average I", event_data -> sample.average_current, "mA",
       "Highest I", event_data -> sample.highest_current,  "mA"); 
Message(event_data -> sample.message);
printf("\n      %-11s = %02d", "Sample port", event_data -> portsample);
printf("\n      ");
print_datetime(event_data -> time_off);
printf("  %3.1f Vbat  %3.1f %cC  PORT = %02d", 
       event_data -> vbat_off, event_data -> celcius_off, 248, event_data -> portend);

printf("\n");
```

The output looks like this:

```
  Intake Flush                101 ml       34 sec  LB 22.5 V  Average I 113.0 mA Highest I 118.0 mA Volume reached
  Flush port  = 00

  Sample                      320 ml      141 sec  LB 22.5 V  Average I 91.0 mA Highest I 97.0 mA Volume reached
  Sample port = 01
  12/09/15 17:11:14  22.6 Vbat  22.5 øC  PORT = 01
```

Notice how the "Average I" and "Highest I" values aren't lining up?  Shouldn't they be right justified by default? I expect the last displayed digit of the float would be to the right most position in the the 4 character space I have designated for the float.  The longs are displaying the way I expected.

Comment: The width of of 4 in `"%4.1f"` is the _minimum_ textual width of the output.  It includes the sign, leading spaces, (an exponent if there was one) as well as digits.

Comment: Please review how to create an MCVE ([How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) or SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/))
— two names and links for the same basic idea. This code is considerably more complex than an MCVE.  There is a lot of extraneous material to be processed that we really shouldn't have to process.

Comment: Thanks everyone...  That was the issue, I would give you all up votes but I don't have the privilege to do so yet.  Also, I apologize for posting so much code for such a simple problem.  From now on my examples will contain the least amount of code to present the problem I am experiencing.

Comment: BTW, as an aside, the symbol for the second is `s`, not `sec`.

Answer (score 3):

For your data, changing %4.1f to %5.1f will solve this problem.  In a %m.nf format specifier, the m is the total width of the field in bytes, not the number of digits preceding the decimal point.

Comment: If there was a negative value, the sign would be included in the count too; the decimal point is counted.  And it is the minimum total width; when more width is needed, more width is used — as ably demonstrated by the sample data in the question.